# ¿Cómo instalar el módulo Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pip

Estoy intentando instalar el modulo Flask-SQLAlchemy y me da el siguiete error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/include/python3.7m/greenlet'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

greenlet entiendo que es una sub-dependencia de Flask-SQLAlchemy y solo da el problema para esa librería, no entiendo muy bien dado que no ocurre para otras dependencias. ¿Solo está necesita permisos?

Estoy con Python 3.7.9

Comment: Pareciera que estas queriendo instalar las librerías a nivel sistema, para eso necesitas permisos de  root, pero aún así, es mejor instalarlas a nivel proyecto. Te sugiero que investigues por el lado de los entornos virtuales que es la forma clásica de manejar el runtime de python a nivel proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte, ocurre que esta instalación se da dentro de un proceso de CI/CD y no tengo posibilidad de crear un entorno virtual.

Answer (score 0):

El usuario que estas utilizando no tiene permisos para modificar /usr/local/include/python3.7m/.

lo podes instalar a nivel usuario así:

```
pip install  greenlet --user
```

o a nivel global como root asi:

```
sudo pip install  greenlet
```

Comment: Gracias, Pero no puedo hacer sudo, este despliegue es un automatismo CI/CD y no tengo esa posibilidad. El caso es porque únicamente me falla esta librería